# Django Display Live Data without page Refresh

Tags: python-3.x, django, ajax

I have developed django application, which basically do tracer route on Cisco devices at a time multiple devices , everything is working fine, but output is displaying after getting output from all devices, I want output to be displayed once we got output from first device, and after getting second that output to be displayed in web page and it go one, please help how to accomplish.
How to use ajax here if we have to use

Answer (score 0):

### Looks like you need to do either AJAX requests or use WebSockets for that kind of thing.

HTTP protocol works in a request-response fashion, so in order to get something you need to ask for it first.

For your problem you can create a simple view that returns your recent data in a JSON format for example with django JsonResponse. And then create a template with a little of JavaScript code to constantly poll your django server for the data and display it on the page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

This approach is fine, but it is not really real time.
If you want your data on the page to update as fast as possible, you should consider using WebSockets. Django Channels is usually the way here (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Ha channels we can use this for requirement, but our application is in production with WSGI, if I use channels I have to change wsgi to asgi.   So I have to use ajax , in that I got your points, but how to constantly call view I have to use for loop or how...

Comment: Yeah, you can use loops in your JavaScript code, but that will probably block something on the page, i'm not very familiar with JS so i can't tell for sure. More conveniently you can try setInterval() function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to just constantly poll your server for updates.